# Difficult Sql query for a forum like application

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a web app that has some similar functionality as stackoverflow. Users can create a post and vote on posts. These posts I call Ideas

I am trying to get a query that returns all posts and also returns a 1 or 0 if the signed in user has a vote on a particular post.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT idea.[IdeaID], 
    Idea.Title, 
    idea.Description,
    idea.Status,
    idea.DateCreated, 
    count(votes.IdeaID) as ideaVoteCount
FROM Idea   
FULL OUTER JOIN Votes 
    on (idea.IdeaID = Votes.IdeaID)
GROUP BY idea.IdeaID,
    Idea.Title, 
    idea.Description, 
    idea.Status,
    idea.DateCreated
```

This is working correctly so far. It is returning all idea posts and a new column with the count each idea has. I now want a column next to it that displays a 1 or 0 for each idea if the user has voted on it based on a userid.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

EDIT: I have a junction? table I am using to store votes. Votes contains an ideaid and  a userid. UserID is coming from a table of user information.

Comment: Where is UserID column? is it in a separate table? add more details..

Comment: Agree with Dark Knight.. there's not enough information here to help.

Comment: I apologize. I am still very new at SQL and this is also my first post on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
SELECT I.[IdeaID], 
    I.Title, 
    I.Description,
    I.Status,
    I.DateCreated, 
    sum(case when votes.IdeaID is null then 0 else 1 end) as ideaVoteCount,
     case when exists(Select 1 from Votes where userid=@userid and ideaid=I.ideaid) then 1 else 0 end as voteexists
FROM Idea I
LEFT JOIN Votes 
    on (I.IdeaID = Votes.IdeaID)
GROUP BY I.IdeaID,
    I.Title, 
    I.Description, 
    I.Status,
    I.DateCreated,
    votes.ideaid
```

Comment: Both answers so far have affected the first ideaVoteCount column as well. Could there be something wrong with my initial design maybe?

Comment: With further testing, this is correctly displaying 1 if the user voted on that idea but in both count columns. What needs changed to keep the first count columns as total votes and second count column as just a 1 if the user voted on that particular idea?

Comment: So close! 1's and 0's were flipped. I changed "then 0 else 1 end as voteexists" to "then 1 else 0 end as voteexists" and it seems to be working! Thank you!

Comment: please Mark as answer if this answers your question.